# Подскажите как подключить индивидуальные прокси в imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

Ребята, подскажите как подключить индивидуальные прокси в `imacros`.
Прокси без авторизации я знаю как прописывать:

> PROXY ADDRESS=176.15.139.29:8080

Пыталась прописать:

> PROXY ADDRESS=176.15.139.29:8080:логин:пароль

Но таким образом скрипт игнорирует прокси.
Хотела уточнить, мне нужно, чтобы было автоматическое подключения, без ручного написания логина и пароля в сплывающую форму.

Comment: нене... так не пойдет, смотрим суда: [ONLOGIN](https://wiki.imacros.net/ONLOGIN)

Comment: Да я знаю про ONLOGIN. Но ONLOGIN не работает в Firefox. Есть ли альтернативный способ?!

Comment: `Syntax Firefox`  - все везде работает, не знаю, что у вас там не работает.

Comment: "The ONLOGIN command no longer works with legacy iMacros for Firefox (v9.0.3 and older) in Firefox 51.0 or newer. It does work with iMacros for Firefox 10 and later in Firefox Quantum (v57 and later)." У меня лиса 55.0.3

Comment: Команда ONLOGIN больше не работает с устаревшими iMacros - от суда вывод, старый софт вас погубит =))

Answer (score 1):

Без блока обработки формы с помощью [ONLOGIN](http://www.imacros.org/komandy/onlogin) не получится
Но разработчики значительно урезали функционал плагина FF, начиная с версии 8.9.7
Поэтому надо установить FireFox версий 35 - 56.02 и плагин версии 8.9.7,
или скачать [FF35 + iMacros](http://www.imacros.org/files)